# Django 1.8 PUT and DELETE method simple implementation

Tags: python, django, rest, http

I've a project that need integration with PUT and DELETE method recently.
However it has being quite large for me to refactory it using Django Restful Project. How can I get PUT and DELETE method, and its data like POST simply?

Is there a quick middleware for it?

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a [read here](https://baxeico.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/put-and-delete-http-requests-with-django-and-jquery/), I think this might be what you are looking for.

> You can use the so called POST TUNNELLING method, that is using a POST
>   request, putting the HTTP header X_METHODOVERRIDE in the request.

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot change the js part. It is sent here via $.ajax's PUT and data.

Comment: I don't think Django constructs any dicts for PUT and DELETE from what I know. Here is the reasoning: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/dxI4qVzrBY4/m_9IiNk_p7UJ

Comment: By the way, you could get the data from the request in request.body if you need to have access to it.

Comment: Could you give me an example that how can I parse the request.body?

Comment: You can inherit in Django the View class and override ...the dispatch method to have access to the request if you want;  reference -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch

Answer (score 1):

You can see how Django constructs the `POST` data from [`request.body`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.body) in the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f576b23a652eba69667ab3ce42aaf5f6b3e6f4ea/django/http/request.py#L272). You should be be able to do something similar.

Assuming the PUT data is form encoded:

```
from django.http.request import QueryDict

def my_put_view(request):
   if request.method = 'PUT':
       PUT = QueryDict(self.body, encoding=request._encoding), MultiValueDict()
       # do something with PUT
```